# Android - setContentView(R.layout.main);

Tags: android, android-studio

I looked into other questions of this type and I followed their instructions, but none of them seem to work. I have a problem where I have this code

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and the error saying `error: cannot find symbol variable main`. I tried importing the name of the package, and all of my .xml files are in order with no errors. What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have an xml file named main in your layouts??

Comment: Do you have a layout file called "main.xml"?

Comment: I have `activity_main.xml`

Comment: You have probably imported a wrong R class that holds up all the references for your resource file. Fix this by importing the right R class!

Comment: Then you should have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

as you dont have an xml file named main.xml in your layout folder..

Comment: ... I donked out on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Change
setContentView(R.layout.main);

to
setContentView(R.layout.**Your_XML_File_Name**.xml);

You have to look into your layout folder and find out your xml file name and put it above instead of **Your_XML_File_Name**.